# Click function not updating global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the global variable `x` when the user clicks a button. However, it is not being changed. I have researched this on Google, and it seems like I'm doing everything right.

testing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>
    <style>
        div {
            border: solid 1px orange;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            font-size: 45px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Click here</button>
    <div><div/>
</body>
</html>
```

tesing.js:

```
var x;
$(document).ready(function() {
    x = 0;
    $("div").text(x);
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        x = 1;
    }); 
    $("div").text(x); //the div stays at "0" even after I click the button
});
```

If I put `$("div").text(x);` inside the click function after `x = 1`, then it works, but I need it to change `x` in the global scope, not the local one, so I can use it in other JS functions in the html file.

**EDIT:**
The reason I'm trying to test `x` outside of the click function is because I'll need to use that updated `x` in a document ready function inside the html file, so I can't do everything inside the click function. Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible? But I thought that's why global variables exist?

Comment: The click event will fire just when you click so then the `x` will be incremented, but the `$("div").text(x);` expression will be executed on DOM ready when the `x` is always `0` as you give it by default, so what you want to do make no sense.

Comment: How do I get later functions (that are not in the click function) to change after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the HTML inside the click handler. `$("div").text(x);` assigns the value of `x` as the text of `$("div")`, it does not bind the text to that variable, so the text must be updated when the value of the variable is updated.

```js
var x = 0;
$("div").text(x);
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("div").text(++x);
});
```

```css
div {
    border: solid 1px orange;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}
div::before {
    content: "x = ";
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Increment</button><br>
<div></div>
```